# JSON: Charset and getting key/value

Tags: php, javascript, json, utf-8, character-encoding

So I have a php script that does this:

```
$rows = array();        
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth2)) {
 $rows[] = array($r['alternative'] => $r['amount']);
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

I get this output:

`[{"\u00e5l":"3"},{"vin":"3"},{"whiskey":"1"},{"gin":"1"},{"rom":"1"},{"vodka":"1"}]`

Problem one: \u00e5 is supposed to be ø. Everything else works with utf8 except this very function, any idea how to fix this?

Second problem is that I cannot seem to get a nice way of reading the data in javascript. I am currently using this code (I know's not that good, but it should work for now):

```
$.each(obj, function(key, val) 
{
counter = counter +1 ;
switch (counter)
    {
        case 0:
            numberOne = key;
            valueOne = val;
            break;
        case 1:
            numberTwo = key;
            valueTwo = val;
            break;
        case 2:
            numberThree = key;
            valueThree = val;
            break;
        case 3:
            numberFour = key;
            valueFour = val;
            break;
        case 4:
            numberFive = key;
            valueFive = val;
            break;
        case 5:
            numberSix = key;
            valuesix = val;
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting UTF-8 encoded data from your database? [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: I am using the same database to generate a poll with the same values, and it prints out just fine. However I am not using JSON for this. I solved it by doing mysql_set_charset( "utf8" ); in my php-connector file. These numbers are used to make a wordcloud of the answers from the poll.

Comment: @Tom Then you're likely using latin1 encoded data throughout your site, whereas `json_encode` and JSON in general explicitly expects UTF-8.

Comment: I've really tried to fix this, for this I use 3 files and they are all set to UTF-8, and they all can manage the custom letters for other aspects, it's just the echo json_encode that turns out as something else :/

Comment: `\u00e5` is a perfectly valid way to encode characters in JSON, if that's what you mean.

Comment: It's just hard for humans to read :P

Comment: Yes, but humans will not read `\u00e5` if and when the JSON is correctly parsed back into data by the browser/Javascript. It's only in the serialized JSON format...

Comment: I just found out that it did, thanks! When I solved problem number 2 number 1 automatically was solved as well :P

Comment: @Tom Good to hear that !!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your second problem you can use

```
for(a in obj)
{
  alert(a +' = '+obj[a]);
}
```

You havn't specified what you want to achive by reading object properties So I left it to you :) hope it helps.

edited :

```
for(a in obj)
    {
      alert(a +' = '+obj[a]);
      for(b in obj[a])
      {
        alert(b+' = '+obj[a][b]); // or   alert(b+'  '+obj[a].b); would work  
      }
    }
```

Comment: I wish it did but it comes out as 0 = [Object object], 1 = [Object object] etc.

Comment: because you object is deeper and the value of the property is itself an object . than one level more let me edit my answer

Comment: You solved both problems in 1! Very nice work :) Thanks!

Comment: @Tom Good to hear that !!!!!!! :)

Comment: @Tom though I didn't understood how the forst problem has been solved :)

Comment: Neither do I, but somehow Javascript encoded it back to ø so it's all good :p

Comment: @Tom great !!!!  :) I wish to share your luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option to json_encode.

The code you use to read out the data does indeed seem sub-optimal, but it's hard to comment on how to improve it, as I can't tell what you're actually doing with the data.

Comment: I am using these data to generate a wordcloud, but when I try to use numberOne my wordcloud just turns out as a big 0. I have mysql_set_charset( "utf8" ); in my php-connector file, and when generating the poll it has no problems printing ø as ø. But I am not using JSON for that.

Comment: The comment section is not a great place to discuss this, but I cannot imagine why you would ever want to split up this array into 6 pairs of variables, which even have numbers in their names! Just keep the array

Comment: It's because I need the values to create my wordcloud like this:
var myTextList = [
     {text: numberOne, weight: parseInt(valueOne)} .... etc

Comment: Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given is what I get.

Comment: @Tom: Then create the myTextList array immediately in your loop. It makes a lot more sense. Second: If you get the 'must be long error' it can mean two things: 1) You're not passing the option as a constant, or: you are running an outdated PHP version (pre 5.4)

Answer (score -3):

You can't pass null values with JSON. Replace them with empty string. I recommend doing it in the query level by

```
case columnname when is null then '' end as newcolumnname
```

Comment: @deceze his problem is not character encoding.

Comment: It's not? *"I solved it by doing mysql_set_charset( "utf8" ); in my php-connector file."*

Comment: @deceze where's your output? the person expects null javascript object

Comment: Where in the question does it say anything about `null`?

Comment: I did specify what the output looks like. It's only the charset that is wrong. My output is correct except for the custom letters.

Comment: @Tom Not sending null values to json encoder or decoder will solve your problem.